# Tridion2013SP1: ClassNotFoundException com.tridion.broker.querying.criteria.content.PageURLCriteria

Tags: 2013, content-delivery, dynamic-linking

We have a standard Tridion2013 SP1 installation - IIS based website, `application\bin` has all of the Tridion DLLs (2013 SP1) and `\lib` includes all of the jars (`cd_broker.jar` etc.) from Tridion installation folder. However, we keep hitting this Java exception and cannot get past this. Double-checked DLL versions, jars and everything seems right, how can we troubleshoot this further? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.broker.querying.criteria.content.PageURLCriteria
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at com.codemesh.bootstrap.JarInputStreamBootstrapper.forName(Unknown Source)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowException(Exception ex)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.NTypeValue.Throw(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst)
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.init()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaClass.get_JObject()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.init()
   at Codemesh.JuggerNET.JavaMethod.CallObject(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArguments args)
   at Com.Tridion.Broker.Querying.Criteria.Content.PageURLCriteria..ctor(String url)
   at Tridion.ContentDelivery.DynamicContent.Query.PageURLCriteria..ctor(String url)
```

Comment: Do you have the lib and config folders below your /bin folder? If not, try that. Also check whether you have a valid cd_licenses.xml in your config folder.

Comment: @Raimond: Please post this as an answer. Since this issue absolutely related with invalid license file.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the lib and config folders below your /bin folder? If not, try that. Also check whether you have a valid **cd_licenses.xml** and **cd_storage_conf.xml** in your `config` folder.

Additionally, check the Event Log to see where Tridion Content Delivery is loading its jars from. If that does not help, check whether the `TRIDION_HOME` variable is set on your server. This might point to a wrong directory.